# JS return result from Java

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, adt, zeroconf

I am attempting to use the following [plugin](https://github.com/vstirbu/ZeroConf) and am having a problem accessing the JAVA result in JS.

Below is a short version on the plugin that relates

**Java:**

```
public void sendCallback(String action, ServiceInfo info) {
    JSONObject status = new JSONObject();
    try {
        status.put("action", action);
        status.put("service", jsonifyService(info));
        Log.d("ZeroConf", "Sending result: " + status.toString());
        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK,
                status);
        result.setKeepCallback(true);
        this.callback.sendPluginResult(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
var ZeroConf = {
watch: function (type, callback) {
    return exec(function (result) {
        if (callback) {
            callback(result);
        }

    }, ZeroConf.fail, "ZeroConf", "watch", [type]);
}};module.exports = ZeroConf;
```

In my html file I am trying to show the result and nothing is working! I am not very familiar with JAVA so I am not sure where the source of my issue it.

**Sample HTML File:**

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    ZeroConf.watch('_http._tcp.local.', function(result) {
```

This is where I dont know how to access the result from JAVA

```
 alert(result)
       // do something with the result


    });
},
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}};
```

**Notes:** Im sure its working because I can see the results from the JAVA side "Log.d"

Answer (score 0):

You get an `object` as the result. You need to parse it or stringify it, depending on what you want to do with it.

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    ZeroConf.watch('_http._tcp.local.', function(result) {
        // Stringify the result to display it all as a string
        resultText = JSON.stringify(result);
        alert(resultText);

        // just display some values from the object
        // for example PORT and NAME
        alert("port: "+result.service.port + ", name: "+result.service.name);

    });
},
```

The result object structure is described on the [plugin's page](https://github.com/vstirbu/ZeroConf).

Comment: I am suspecting that there is a issue with my implementation of the Java and the plugin. The result is not returned and therefore I get a undefined when printing the value of the result.

Comment: I'm maintaining this plugin and I would like to have more info about your problem. Have you installed the app using cordova-cli? What Android version and device type are you using?